# RSelenium - NoSuchElement even though xpath is being used?

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

I'm trying to use find element to enter a username. This is the HTML

UPDATED: Added site - https://riversidescore.com/

```
<input class="login-input" type="text" placeholder="Username" id="fld_tb_3" tabindex="0" maxlength="128" aria-required="true" aria-labelledby="userLbl" value="">
```

Although that id=fld_tb_3 is dynamic and changes when data is entered into the field.

This is the full xpath

```
/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/input
```

And the xpath

```
//*[@id="fld_tb_31"]
```

I am trying to use the following code but the element is not being found. I even tried using the class to no luck.
Class

```
remDr$findElement(
  using ='xpath', "//div[@class='login-input']/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/input"
)
```

Wildcard

```
remDr$findElement(
  using ='xpath', "//*[starts-with(@id,'fld_tb_')/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/input"
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Added Error Message

```
Selenium message:{"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with xpath '//*[@id=\"fld_tb_3\"]'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*","Accept-Encoding":"deflate, gzip, br","Content-Length":"49","Content-Type":"application/json","Host":"localhost:4444","User-Agent":"libcurl/7.61.1 r-curl/4.3.2 httr/1.4.2"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\":\"xpath\",\"value\":\"//*[@id=\\\"fld_tb_3\\\"]\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/b128fad0-ac65-11ec-ae40-d37036d5ead6/element"}}

Error:   Summary: NoSuchElement
     Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
     class: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the link to website.

Comment: My apologies, I added the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do,

```
#enter username
user <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/input')
user$sendKeysToElement(list("my_username"))

#enter passowrd (has to use full xpath)
pass <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[4]/input')
pass$sendKeysToElement(list("my_password"))

#click on login  
remDr$findElement(using = "xpath",'//*[@id="root"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/input')$clickElement()
```

[image]

Comment: Can I ask what browser you are using? I am using phantomJS and user function does not work on my end.  I added my error.

Comment: I am using `firefox`. I have modified code to include full xpath, see if it works now.

Comment: Even with the full path I cannot find the elements

Comment: Strange, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to identify the element with following xpath for username.

```
//input[@placeholder='Username' and @class='login-input']
```

so your code will be

```
 remDr$findElement(
  using ='xpath', "//input[@placeholder='Username' and @class='login-input']"
)
```

xpath for password element

```
//input[@placeholder='Password' and @class='login-input']
```

xpath for sign in button

```
//input[@value='Sign In' and @class='login-button']
```